# RESTful service return HTTP Response with Message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

How is it possible to leverage the HTTP Status Codes in REST services on aspnet core? Eventually even including a message if something went wrong.

For example:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<MyModel> Get(int id)
    {
        if (id == 0)
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        ...
    }
```

this code obviously returns the error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' to 'MyModel'`

One solution would be to always return a HTTP200 and a couple of extra properties to `MyModel` like `Status`, `Success` or `Message`, but this defeats the purpose of being RESTful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Ok` or `BadRequest` method. You can use `Task<ObjectResult>` as your return type.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ObjectResult> Get(int id)
{
   if(id==0)
      return BadRequest(new {Messagae = "Something is not correctT"});
   var result = await GetSomeMyModelObject();

   return Ok(result);
}
```

You do not need to necessarily call `Ok` method, you can simply return your data. The serializer will take care of setting the correct response headers (200 OK status) This will also work

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
{
   if(id==0)
      return BadRequest(new {Messagae = "Something is not correctT"});
   var result = await GetSomeMyModelObject();

   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning `Task<MyModel>`, return `Task<IActionResult>`:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id)
{
    if (id == 0) return BadRequest();
    // ...

    return Ok(model);
}
```

There are a number of controller helper methods (see the [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/actions.html#controller-helper-methods)) such as `BadRequest()`, `Ok()`, `NotFound()`, `Created()`, and so on. These map onto the HTTP response codes that you'd expect.

Comment: @EdwinvanVliet That's what `Ok(model)` does for you: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L349

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me instead

```
 return BadRequest("Something is not correct");
```